# Allow UFW rules in specific IP range

Tags: terminal, raspberry-pi, raspbian, ufw

I need to setup some firewall rules but I do not want to open them to public since I am running an nginx server, how can I allow the follow rules only locally from IP address 192.168.178.0 to .64?

```
sudo ufw allow 80/tcp
sudo ufw allow 53/tcp
sudo ufw allow 53/udp
sudo ufw allow 67/tcp
sudo ufw allow 67/udp
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only use ranges inside of binary numbers (2,4,8,16...) For your case would be only valid fron 192.168.178.0 to 192.167.178.63. In case of being valid for you, the rules would these ones:

```
sudo ufw allow proto tcp from  192.168.178.0/26 to any port 80
sudo ufw allow proto tcp from  192.168.178.0/26 to any port 53
sudo ufw allow proto udp from  192.168.178.0/26 to any port 53
sudo ufw allow proto tcp from  192.168.178.0/26 to any port 67
sudo ufw allow proto udp from  192.168.178.0/26 to any port 80
```

Comment: These give me an error: Bad source address

Comment: @Daniell It may be requesting you with netmask value; I have changed it for a netmask of 26 ; host min 192.168.178.1 host max 192.168.178.62

Comment: So after running these I still cannot seem to get access locally, if I run the commands in my question they do work, are there any additional commands I need to run?